# Autovoice stoped working till I close chrome

Tags: tasker

When I launch autovoice with voice command, it works first time, sometimes twice, but then hangs (totally no reaction) until I do one of the two things (I switch screen to google now which was closed by autovoice, or if I launch auto voice app)

Additionally, I must say that, when I say my command correctly, sometimes google now search stays active on the screen, and sometimes it is closed by tasker or autovoice. When it stays, all works fine.

I have samsung s7, android 7.0 no root.

here is my profile, task and command if you need I can record this strange behaviour
[image]

Comment: Might be due to entrance and exit tasks, check if you entered them correctly.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat my task is only react for voice command and do get request, thats all, how can I check entering and exiting them ?

Comment: How does  your profile look like? I mean lets say you linked your profile (trigger)  to your task right , so my question is what does that profile look like? Mind sending a screenshot?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat added image to my question, what i noticed is that sometimes google now search result is close and sometimes not, when is closed by tasker I need to make it active and voice recognision starts working again.

Comment: I get the feeling that autovoice is getting its process/service killed by the system in low oom conditions